# ODE) $y'' + 2y' = 1 + t^2 + e^{-2t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with the ODE problem:

$y'' + 2y' = 1 + t^2 + e^{-2t}$

This problem is in "judicious guessing" chapter of Braun's "Differential Equations and Their Applications".

The trick he taught in the chapter is to set $\psi$ = $A_0 + A_1 t + ... A_n t^n$ and determine constant terms. Also, he taught the technique to deal with such equations as $(1+t+t^3)e^5t$.

But, he is never explicit as to equations with the above form. I tried several tricks, but they don't work. Can anybody help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you learned characteristic equations? And $y=y_c+y_p$?

Comment: I would advise: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/first-order-linear-odes/MIT18_03SCF11_s4_5text.pdf

Comment: @KittyL Thanks for comment! Yes. I've learned characteristic equations applied linear and homogenous second order DE, but I have no idea how to apply to that case. I'm not sure of y = $y_c +y_p$.

Comment: @MattAllegro Thanks Matt! But I'm not sure the text can help me.. The text seems to deal with first-order cases..

Comment: You're welcome! Superposition applies also for higher order. Could you solve, separately, $y'' + 2y' = 1$, $y'' + 2y' = t^2$ and $y'' + 2y' = e^{-2t}$?

Comment: Let z=y'. This leads to a first order linear ODE. I suppose that you know how to solve the linear first order ODEs ?

Comment: @MattAllegro Thanks! I get the point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution $y$ is equal to $y_c+y_p$, where $y_c$ is the solution of the homogeneous equation, $y_p$ is a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation.

For $y_c$, set up the characteristic equation $r^2+2r=0$. This will give you $y_c$.

For $y_p$, separate the right hand side into two parts $1+t^2$ and $e^{-2t}$ and use superposition principle.

For the $1+t^2$, since constant is also a solution for the homogeneous equation, you can use $t(A+Bt+Ct^2)$ as your undetermined function.

For $e^{-2t}$ though, it is also a solution of the homogeneous part, so you need to try $Ate^{-2t}$. If that fails, $At^2e^{-2t}$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for super clear answer!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: You need the extra factor of $t$ also for the eigenvalue $0$ and thus the $1+t^2$ part of the right hand side.

Comment: @LutzL: Thanks for the reminder. But I think the $Bt$ term already takes care of that. You don't need an extra $t$ for the $t^2$ term. The only difference is we can drop the $A$ for the trial solution.

Comment: But you do not get a third order term, which is necessary to get the quadratic term in $1+t^2$, see answer by Essam.

Comment: @LutzL: I see. Thanks! I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can integrate both sides to get a first differential equation as follow:
$$y'+2y=t+t^3/3-1/2e^{-2t}+C$$
and you can find the $C$ from the boundary condition

Comment: nice work. (+1). you can take few more more steps; just to be complete. $\left(ye^{2t}\right)'=te^{2t} + \frac 1 3 t^2e^{2t} - \frac 12 + Ce^{2t} \to ye^{2t} = \frac 12 te^{2t} + \cdots$

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the solution of the homogeneous problem $y''+2y'=0$, the characteristic equation is $m^2+2m=0\Rightarrow m=0,-2$, so $y_c=A+Be^{-2t}$. We want to find $y=y_c+y_p$ that solves the full problem, so we just need to find $y_p$, if the right hand side contains a polynomial of some degree, then the ansatz must contain a polynomial of that degree as well, similarly for exponential or trigonometric functions as well. But consider the case where $y_c$ already contains a polynomial of the same degree as the right hand side, or an exponential function that is in the right hand side etc. This is the case that we have: $y_c$ contains $Ae^{-2t}$, and the right hand side contains $e^{-2t}$, this tells us that $(e^{-2t})''+2(e^{-2t})'=0$, so if we try an ansatz for $y_p$ containing $e^{-2t}$, we will get a zero when plugging into the ODE, but we want $e^{-2t}$ to appear, so we multiply by $t$, since then $$(te^{-2t})''+2(te^{-2t})'=t((e^{-2t})''+2(e^{-2t})')-2e^{-2t}=-2e^{-2t},$$
now if we choose the right constant $Cte^{-2t}$ will give us what we want.

To deal with the polynomial, the ansatz must contain a polynomial of degree 3, i.e. $t(D+Et+Ft^2)$, so overall we set $$y_p=Cte^{-2t}+t(D+Et+Ft^2).$$

Comment: Since also constants solve the homogeneous equation, you need $t(D+Et+Ft^2)$ as the trial solution for the $1+t^2$ part of the inhomogeneity.

Comment: this is included in the ansatz, because we have the $Et$ term

Comment: But you also need a third order term to get the quadratic term in the inhomogeneity. See answer by Essam.

Comment: True, let me edit